# Backgrounder process in Tableau is not started?

Tags: tableau-api

I had install Tableau 9.0 on VM - Windows server 2008.
I use below command to clear logs and Restarted tableau Server, but after that i check status of tableau server in this Backgrounder process is not started.

[image]

After that i am not able seen my publish workbooks in tableau server administrator login.

I appreciate your suggestion, on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you see anything in the server logs? http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/logs_loc.htm

Comment: I have uninstall and install again now it works, i am not able to figure out what is issue in server.

Comment: The backgrounder being down wouldn't have affected published workbooks, although as to why it was down is another question. If you'd like to know, create a support case and request a root cause analysis, providing the date/time of the backgrounder being down, Server logs and Windows Event Logs.